# HTMX active search with multiple input sources

Tags: htmx

So, I was playing a bit with HTMX and designed a small application that aggregates news articles from different sources and shows them on a single feed.

For this feed, I wanted to make an advanced search, which includes:

1. Search bar (input) for filtering by article's title.
2. A drop-down (select) with news source options (BBC, CNN etc).
3. A submit button

I want to trigger the whole search on the following events:

1. User inputs something to the search bar (with 500ms debounce time).
2. User selected a different news source filter option.
3. User clicks on submit button.

For that purpose, I have used a `<form>` with nested `<input>`, `<select>` and `<button>` elements:

```html
<div id="articles-search">
    <form id="search-form"
          hx-get="/"
          hx-target="#articles-search"
          hx-swap="innerHTML"
          hx-vals="{search: document.getElementById('search').value, source: document.getElementById('source').value}"
        hx-trigger="keyup delay:500ms, change">
        <label for="search">Search</label>
        <input type="search" id="search"
               name="search" placeholder="Type here.."
               {% if existing_search %}value="{{ existing_search }}"{% endif %}/>

        <label for="source">Source</label>
        <select name="source" id="source">
            <option value="">All</option>
            {% for source in sources %}
                <option value="{{ source.value }}"
                        {% if selected_source == source.value %}selected{% endif %}>
                    {{ source.value }}
                </option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>

        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>

    <div id="search-results">
        {% if articles %}
            <hr>
            {% for article in articles %}
                <h2>{{ article.title }}</h2>
                <p>{{ article.source.value }}</p>
                <p>{{ article.description }}</p>
                <p><a href="{{ article.url }}" target="_blank">Read more</a></p>
                <hr/>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a part of document, that is rendered only if `HX-Request` header is provided. I am using [jinja2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/) library to render HTML templates in Python.

With this setup everything works as expected for me, except the fact that when form is submitted by `keyup` or `change` events, it doesn't put the `search` and `source` values to query parameters list. I want to put them in the URL, so you can copy and share the URL with others and the others would see the same search applied.

However, when the form is submitted using the submit button or when pressing ENTER while searching, it does put the form values to the query parameters.

My question is:

Is there any way to force HTMX to put form values to query parameters on each `hx-trigger` event?

I was trying to use `hx-vals` for this purpose, but that seems to have no effect.

Also, Copilot Chat suggested me to put the next script:

```js
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var searchForm = document.getElementById('search-form');
    var searchInput = document.getElementById('search');
    var sourceInput = document.getElementById('source');

    function updateHxVals() {
      searchForm.setAttribute('hx-vals', JSON.stringify({
        search: searchInput.value,
        source: sourceInput.value
      }));
    }

    searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', updateHxVals);
    sourceInput.addEventListener('change', updateHxVals);
  });
```

but that also did not resolve the issue

Comment: One question at a time, please. [ask]

Comment: Sorry for that, but these questions are kinda related to each other and just help me solve my concrete problem with passing form values to URL params and find out the best possible practice to solve this problem.

Next time I ask a question on StackOverflow, I will try to stick to the one question rule.

Comment: How about this time sticking to the rules. Your question is already up for closing.

Comment: Okay, I've only left the first question here

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger event from specific elements by using `from:` selector. You can also combine it with comma seperated events to get all different type of events in your form. It should allow you to preserve all values as well.

In your case, smth like this should work:

```
hx-trigger="submit, input changed delay:500ms from:input, search, change from:select"
```

Comment: Thanks! I've missed the part with `from:` selector which is indeed extra useful for my use case

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `hx-push-url="true"` attribute on your `<form/>` tag. It should work as you expect and it should answer your first (and maybe second) question.